# Use capture group within gsub() as index/name for another object (R)

Tags: r, regex, gsub

the essence of my question boils down to whether it is possible to use a captured group (via. `\\1`) within gsub() to access elements of another object?
For example:
Finding a pattern within each string of a list of strings and then returning just the captured pattern works like this:

```
gsub("(Some_pattern).*", "\\1" , List_of_strings)
```

I was wondering if something like the following is possible:

```
gsub("(Some_pattern).*", object["\\1"] , List_of_strings)
```

Basically using the captured group to access an element with the same name as the captured group.
With the above syntax the error "subscript out of bounds" is produced - which I assume means that `\\1` is not interpreted as the captured group, but as literally `\\1`.
Of course the same result can be achieved with different methods, but I was wondering if the interpretation of a captured group within gsub is possible?
Thanks!

Comment: Use `gsubfn`...

Comment: That was easy. Thank you!

Comment: Actually, there are other ways, too, but I think `gsubfn` is, as you say, easier.